# How to use this AdaptiveTrigger in UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am writing an **UWP Application**.

I added **SplitView** (for hamburger purposes) to page.

In **SplitView Pane**, I have two Items:

- SellButtonGrid
- SellButtonGridAlternate

Visibility of above two items depend on two **conditions**:

- Minimum 520 Windows Height
- and SplitViewPane opened or closed.

That means 4 cases :

> 1. Windows height lesser than 520 and splitviewpane closed
> 2. Windows height lesser than 520 and splitviewpane open
> 3. Windows height larger than 520 and splitviewpane closed
> 4. Windows height larger than 520 and splitviewpane open

**For splitview open or close I use:**

```
<VisualState x:Name="SplitViewOpen">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=LayoutSplitView,
  Path=IsPaneOpen}" />
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="SplitViewClosed">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=LayoutSplitView,
  Path=IsPaneOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}" />
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

**For detecting height below or above 520 I use:**

```
<VisualState x:Name="SmallHeight">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="0" />
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="LargeHeight">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="520" />
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

But, the results are not what I expected.
How to merge these visual states??

**I tried using:**
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2016/02/an-adaptivetrigger-that-works-with.html

I used above solution, so:
**My reworked code:**

```
xmlns:Utils="using:DellApp.Utils"
xmlns:converters="using:DellApp.Converters"
xmlns:windowsStateTriggers="using:WindowsStateTriggers"
```

Newly created states:

```
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="520" MaxWindowHeight="18000" />

  <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=LayoutSplitView,
  Path=IsPaneOpen,
  Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}" />
  </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>

<VisualState x:Name="SplitViewCollapsed_SmallHeight">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowHeight="519"
  MinWindowHeight="0" />
  <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=LayoutSplitView,
  Path=IsPaneOpen,
  Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}" />
  </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>

<VisualState x:Name="SplitViewOpen_SmallHeight">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowHeight="519"
  MinWindowHeight="0" />
  <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=LayoutSplitView,
  Path=IsPaneOpen}" />
  </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>

<VisualState x:Name="SplitViewOpen_LargeHeight">
  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="520" MaxWindowHeight="18000"/>
  <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=LayoutSplitView,
  Path=IsPaneOpen}" />
  </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
  <VisualState.Setters>
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
  <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

So, what I did was, I added [CompositeStateTrigger from WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers) but I am not able to trigger it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a demo from your codes and reproduced the problem. After researching, I found out the following problems:

1. `Binding` does not work with `StateTrigger`. But `x:Bind` works perfectly,so you can use `x:Bind` instead, and don't forget to specify the `Mode=OneWay` for `x:Bind`.
2. `Operator="And"` need to be specified on `windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger`.

So your XAML should be fixed like below:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:BooleanNegationConverter x:Name="BooleanNegationConverter" x:Key="BooleanNegationConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">//use Operator='And' here
                        <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="520" MaxWindowHeight="18000" />
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind LayoutSplitView.IsPaneOpen,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}" />
                </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="SplitViewCollapsed_SmallHeight">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowHeight="519" MinWindowHeight="0" />
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind LayoutSplitView.IsPaneOpen,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}" />
                    </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="SplitViewOpen_SmallHeight">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowHeight="519" MinWindowHeight="0" />
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind LayoutSplitView.IsPaneOpen}" />
                    </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="SplitViewOpen_LargeHeight">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <Utils:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="520" MaxWindowHeight="18000"/>
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind LayoutSplitView.IsPaneOpen}" />
                    </windowsStateTriggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SellButtonGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="SellButtonGridAlternate.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And here is the Sample that I made: [AdaptiveTriggerSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/AdaptiveTriggerSample)

Comment: Yup Worked!. Thanks a lot